# will installing sharepoint enterprise 2013 on windows server 2012 R2 requires more specifications compared to windows 2008 R2

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, installation, configuration, windows-server

I have installed SP 2013 SP1 on windows server 2008 R2 many times. and now i will do my first SP 2013 installation inside windows server 2012 R2 instead of windows server 2008 R2. so i need to know if i can follow the same hardware specification i am currently using, or installing SP 2013 under windows server 2012 requires more RAM  , processors and disk space ? or the differences are not that much ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their is no change in Hardware requirement between windows server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2. You will be fine.

Only thing, Windows Server 2012 R2 is only supported on a SharePoint Server 2013 Service Pack 1 environment.

Comment: so you mean that i need to install sharepoint 2013 SP1 for it work , is this correct ?

Comment: yes, https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2891274?wa=wsignin1.0